# Rails: How to use initializer code inside gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using the `okcomputer` gem for a Rails app (All you need to do to use this gem is to place some code in an initializer).

I'd like to wrap this gem inside a custom gem that can be used without an initializer. I hope to be able to use this gem in several dockerized microservices just by installing it.

I read that it's possible to put initializer code in an `init.rb` file at the root of the gem. In my case, that doesn't seem to be working (the routes generated by okcomputer are not found), but I'm not sure where the issue lies.

In general, can I expect code in `init.rb` to behave like code in an initializer?

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is probably to create a Railties and run your code in an `after_initialize` hook.

```rb
module Gemname
  class MyCoolRailtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    config.after_initialize do
     OKComputer::Registry.register "resque_critical", 
     OKComputer::ResqueBackedUpCheck.new("critical", 10)
    end
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html